# How do I use items selected in a spinner to translate TextViews?

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, translation

I have made a spinner that has a bunch of languages as the item's and I want to make it so that when a user selects a certain language, that selected TextViews will be translated while leaving others untranslated. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

```
<string-array name="Languages">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Tiếng Việt</item>
    <item>中文/</item>
    <item>हिंदी</item>
    <item>العربية</item>
    <item>Español</item>
</string-array>

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,     R.array.Languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

above is my spinner set up. below is an example of one of the text views.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/airport"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must change the Locale language when you select an item of the spinner:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) { 
  myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
  Resources res = getResources(); 
  DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
  Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
  conf.locale = myLocale; 
  res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
  Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class); 
  startActivity(refresh); 
finish();
}
```

After doing so, the value Android will look for should be stored in strings.xml file, with the corresponding key:

English: values/strings.xml

```
<string name="airport">AIRPORT</string>
```

Spanish: values-es/strings.xml

```
<string name="airport">AEROPUERTO</string>
```